# Change the Language format of TEXT function in Microsoft Office Excel

Tags: excel, vba, internationalization, ms-office, date-formatting

I have searched a lot the web but I couldn't find a solution on the following problem:

In Cell A1, I have inserted a date.

For example `42736`, (which is 1 January 2017).

In Cell B1, I want to display the following:

```
"The result is: January 2017"
```

In Cell B1, the formula is:

```
="The result is: " &TEXT(A1;"MMMM YYYY")
```

However, because my computer has German regional format, I have the following two issues:

1) The name of the month is in German and not in English

2) It does not understand the YYYY.

For the second issue, I have found a solution of creating the following UDF:

```
' standard date format regardless of excel language
Public Function STDTEXT$(ByVal Value, ByVal strFormat)
    STDTEXT = VBA.Format$(Value, strFormat)
End Function
```

**Question**

Is there any solution to overcome the first obstacle?

I want to return the month name in English, regardless of the local regional settings of the user.

Regards

Thanasis

Comment: I'd prefer not to change my whole system over to multiple regional languages for testing so could you try `=text(a1, "[$-x-sysdate]mmmm yyyy")`.  This uses the universal language format mask that comes from cell formatting.

Comment: You might also try this cell formatting mask in B1: `\T\h\e\ \r\e\s\u\l\t\ \i\s\: [$-x-sysdate]mmmm yyyy` and simply put `=A1` in B1.

Comment: Two issues with above suggestion: assuming e.g. German language settig it's necessary to use as well the localized form `sysdat` instead of `sysdate`, JJJJ instead of YYYY, i.e. `="=TEXT(A1; ""[$-x-sysdat]MMMM JJJJ"")"` as to accept the localiszed result, e.g. "...: Januar 2017"

Answer (score 1):

You can use create external table `D1:E12`:

```
1   January
2   February
3   March
4   April
5   May
6   June
7   July
8   August
9   September
10  October
11  November
12  December
```

And then use:

```
="The result is: "&VLOOKUP(MONTH(A1),$D$1:$E$12,2,FALSE)&" "&YEAR(A1)
```

Comment: I thought about that solution but I an looking for a more universal solution that it will work for MMM too.

Comment: Clever idea, but still it's not possible that Excel i SO MUCH translated that format string are different across locales

Comment: Posted a (late) answer how to get *English month names* independant from regional settings and based on a single range reference only instead of additionally using localized format patterns :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue I have used following workaround solution

In separate field/sheet created Language Check:

Cell `A1`: `=NA()` - just inserts `#N/A` in the cell

Cell `A2`: `=FORMULATEXT(A1)` - converts `=NA()` function into plain text

Cell `A3`: `=IF(A2="=NA()", "English", IF(A2="=NV()", "German", "Other"))` - while opening a file Excel automatically converts functions into installed language, and English NA becomes NV (nicht verfügbar), and cell shows German.

Further in date cell `B1` I used `=IF($A$3="English", "DD.MM.YYYY", IF($A$3="German", "TT.MM.JJJJ", "ERROR (Language must be English or German"))`

(Although this solution works if the user has the same language in Windows and Excel).

Answer (score 0):

**Example call via UDF**

This approach demonstrates how to get English month names independant from regional settings and based on a single range reference only instead of additionally using localized format patterns.

With cell formula

```
="The result is " & endate(A1)
```

one gets the English month name of a date value in A1, independant from regional setting:

```
"The result is: January 2017"
```

**User defined function `EnDate()`**

```
Function EnDate$(dat#)
' Purpose: return English month name plus year
' Note:    international codes ("patterns") at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693(VS.85).aspx
  Const EN = 409
  EnDate = Application.Text(DateSerial(6, Month(dat), 1), "[$-" & EN & "]mmmm") & " " & Year(dat)
End Function
```

**Related link**

[How to create a calendar Input in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel/54689596#54689596)