# VBA listview problem with windows10 and excel 2016

Tags: vba, listview, excel-2016

I have a problem with VBA-Excel 2016 in Windows 10.
I have registered the "MSCOMCTL.OCX" file with sysWow64/Regsvr32.exe and the "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)" reference point on the SysWoW64 folder but ListView control not working!

Help me please!

Comment: Please read [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you intend to redistribute your code, don't use MSCOMCTL.OCX. These are VB6 controls intended to work in a 32-bit host. See the introduction in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54650417/1188513)

Comment: these solutions did not help.