# Is there a way to use a DatePicker on a UserForm in Excel 64bit without having to download a third party add on?

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, 64-bit, userform

Our company uses some Excel workbooks with UserForms that contain a LOT of datepickers. I'm currently testing a system upgrade which is moving us from 32bit to 64bit systems, and it appears from my extensive googling that there is no native support for datepicker in 64bit systems. I'm currently using Excel2016, but will be upgrading to Excel2019 soon.

Is there a workaround to including datepickers in UserForms in 64bit systems that doesn't involve downloading a third party extension? There is absolutely zero chance of our IT dept approving the download of a third party add-on onto every system, so it's either going to have to be a Microsoft solution (which I don't think exists) or some kind of homebrew code. Googling has got me nowhere because it just recommended third party add-ons.

Comment: What forces you to use`Office 2019 x64`and  not`Office 2019 x86`? Stay on x86 as there are some traps on switching to x64 (e.g WinAPI calls). For x64, e.g.  search on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+datepicker  to find great vba coding samples

Comment: I think you are going to have to write your own replacement.

Comment: See this post showing a calendar widget **not** dependant on ocx or 32/64 bit [How can I create a calendar Input in VBA/Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel/54689596#54689596) :-)

Comment: Here is another calendar: [Excel Custom Calendar Control](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174284/excel-custom-calendar-control)