# VBA Excel - Add references programmatically

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I built a excel macro using the "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library" reference, but when I send the file to other people they get this error: "***Can’t find project or library***".

This file will be used by a lot of people, so I have to add it from VBA Code.

I'm using this code that runs when you open the excel file, which is returning the following error: "***Error in loading DLL***"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSOUTL.OLB\"
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Because you are early binding. Use late binding. It is not necessary that you and the other person is using the same version of MS Office.

Comment: Probably because the other person uses another version of Office (not 15.0). If this is the case then use Late Binding (works without references) instead of Early Binding (uses references). See http://excelmatters.com/2013/09/23/vba-references-and-early-binding-vs-late-binding/

Comment: [From the comment below my deleted answer]... Would you be distributing `mscomct2.ocx` with the excel file? If yes then you will have to get an elevated registration of mscomct2.ocx. This ocx is not native to VBA environment. It is a VB6 control and should be avoided in such a case.

Comment: Quick Question: Why are you even using `mscomct2.ocx`?

Comment: For a drop down calendar, so the user can pick a date and don't write it manually

Comment: You might be interested in [How can I create a calendar input in VBA Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel) which comes with pure VBA.

Comment: Yes, i would. If I dont need to use any references it would be much simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to keep the early binding you could use the GUID in order to add the libray, i.e.

```
Sub AddOL_Ref()

Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.REFERENCES. _
    AddFromGuid "{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 1, 0

End Sub
```

Advantage of using the GUID is that it is constant and does not change with the version of the program.

[Here](https://www.excelcise.org/add-or-remove-object-library-reference-via-vba/) one finds an extened discussion on dis/advantages of early resp. late binding.

Comment: Before you add the GUID, remove the broken references as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879825/how-to-add-a-reference-programmatically/9880276#9880276) :)

Comment: Right, and one also need to check if the reference has already been added regardless if you use AddFromGUID or AddFromfile. Broken references are cause for headaches anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it doesn't return errors this way, but I need to add another reference, from a file I downloaded (mscomct2.ocx), so I don't know if I can use AddFromGuid for this one. What could I do?

Comment: Each reference has a property GUID which you can determine with VBA, for example if `oRef` is the reference then `oRef.GUID` will give you the GUID. [Here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=278) is code how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the references & use late binding

or you can also try this. Send your code to one of the user having 2010MS.

**Goto VBA > Tools > References**

Check for any missing references. You may have ***Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library*** showing as missing. Un-check this, browse down and select ***Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library***.