# How to get months in German in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need my code to create a folder named with german month:
 not 05 March
but 05 März

```
Dim strMonth  As String
 strMonth =  Format(Date, "mm")
 ' Check for month folder and create if needed
If Len(Dir("C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\TestDaty\" & client & "\" & Year(Date) & "\" & strMonth & " " & MonthName(Month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\TestDaty\" & client & "\" & Year(Date) & "\" & strMonth & " " & MonthName(Month(Date), False)
End If
```

so maybe some country code here?
MonthName(Month(Date)
Please help me!!! :)

Comment: You could store the translation of all English months and corresponding German months as key:value pairs in a dictionary. And then do `month_in_german = dict(month)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your locale is set to German I guess something like `Format(Date, "mmmm")` should do (works for me). Otherwise, if you just need to create German named folders you can use a language-code (LCID) in combination with `WorksheetFunction.Text()`:

```
WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "[$-407]mmmm")
```

Where `[$-407]` is the [language-code](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011782_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html) to return a German monthname!

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick anwer!!!  strMonth = WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "[$-407]mmmm") works perfect for me!

Comment: FYI You might be interested having a look a related multilingual function at [Create a calendar input in VBA-Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel/54689596#54689596)