# How can I copy a date from excel to powerpoint through vba and forcing english format regardless of local formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, locale

I have dates in Excel that I need to pass to PowerPoint, but they keep getting formatted to my local formatting (portuguese). I need to force them to be in english format and have been searching but no solution worked for me.

I already tried SetThreadLocale, changing the formatting on excel and forcing it by code, but I was trying to avoid the last one.

Here's my code:

```
Sub ExportToPPT()
    Dim ppt As Object
    Dim pptpres As Object

    Dim presentationDate As Date
    presentationDate = #3/21/2024#

    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    Root = "C:\PPT_REPORTS\"
    template = Root & "ppt_template.pptx"
    Set pptpres = ppt.Presentations.Open(Filename := template)
    
    pptpres.slides(1).Shapes.Item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(presentationDate, "mmmm dd")
End Sub
```

And here's the result:[Image says "março 21"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBDZs.png)

I want to force it to be "March 21" without changing windows' regional formatting

Comment: Try `WorksheetFunction.Text(Date, "[$-409]mmmm dd")`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61977789/7599798

Comment: @FunThomas Do you have a link to a list of those codes?

Comment: Just look to the answer I linked - there is another link pointing to a page where a lot of them are listed. A more complete list I found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c - However, I cannot tell how many of those are actively supported in Excel

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks. I also found a list [here](https://snb-vba.eu/VBA_Fill_combobox_listbox_en.html#L_5.2).

Comment: @FunThomas I already tried that with no success, powerpoint just keeps forcing the locale on the date format

Answer (score 0):

### Force US Month Name

```vb
Sub ExportToPPT()
    
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\PPT_REPORTS\"
    Const FILE_NAME As String = "ppt_template.pptx"
    
    Dim presentationDate As Date: presentationDate = #3/21/2024#
    Dim DateString As String:
    DateString = Application.Text(presentationDate, "[$-409]mmmm dd")
    
    'Debug.Print DateString
    
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FOLDER_PATH & FILE_NAME

    Dim ppt As Object: Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Dim pptpres As Object: Set pptpres = ppt.Presentations.Open(FilePath)
    
    pptpres.Slides(1).Shapes.Item(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DateString

End Sub
```