# How to run userform with DTPickers without MS Windows Common Controls (mscomct2.ocx)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have excel workbook with userforms and I'd to create something "user friendly". That's why I use DTPickres in my userforms. It is ok, but I can't load this object in computers with our Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0 (SP6). In effect, functionality are available only in my computer (office 356 / 32-bit). If, I want to use this excel in another computer, I get error and I have to install mscomct2.ocx.

Is it possible to run this userforms with DTPickres in another computer with out SP6? or is it possible to add reference to excel as... somting like libraries?

The target is open userform with DTPicker without reconfiguration of office / windows, because sometimes I don't have access to computer.

Thanks in advence!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/date-and-time-picker-control-reference is the API that the OCX wraps.

Comment: [This might be an alternate approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel).

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! That solution is good!