# VBA Common Control On Others PC

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I need information.
I am work on Microsoft Excel 365 (2016 32 Bit) and I have registered and installed mscomctl.ocx sp6 to get some additional control on my VBA project such as Date Picker, Listview Control, etc.
So far all works just fine on my PC.

My question, if my excel VBA project run on others computer that mscomctl.ocx sp6 not installed and registered, should my excel VBA project work fine too?.
If not, then I will considering to use any common control own by mscomctl.ocx sp6 and use only the excel 365 controls default. Or any others way to make it works fine on others computer as mentioned?.

Thank you.

Comment: No. The OCX would need to be installed along with your application, or it won't work.

Comment: These controls are intended for VB6, not VBA7; they'll only work on a 32-bit install.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use mscomctl.ocx. There are many reasons for it. Two of them have been mentioned above by Ken and Mat. I can help you with an alternative for the date control. You may want to see [How can I create a calendar input in VBA Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel). For other controls, I am sure (unless it is a complex control like treeview), alternate "arrangements" can me made :)

Comment: Thank you. Ken White, Mathieu Guindon for the information  Siddharth Rout, I have visit your suggested link and download sample file there. The custom calendar/date picker just work fine.  By the way, I found this link : "Compatibility Issues working with Application in Older Version Of Office", https://officetricks.com/create-listview-in-vba-at-runtime/. In case my project also have a Listview  and Datagrid control. So, is the solution is create the controls at runtime by call OLEObjects for the controls?.

Comment: Instead of a listview/datagris, you can use a multicolumn listbox?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am use muliticolumn listbox