# I have VBS code for picking a date in an Excel 2016 spreadsheet. When I run it in Excel 365 I get a compile error. Why?

Tags: excel, vba, date, office365, picker

I created a VBA program to pick a date in an Excel 2016 spreadsheet. This has been working exceptionally well, and all my people love it. Recently our company upgraded from Excel 2016 to Excel 365. After the upgrade things went south. When I went to run the program I got an error message. "Compile Error: Method or data member not found." This is the error message I get when running a VBA program in Excel 365. It worked in Excel 2016.

This worked in Excel 2016 but it does not work in Excell 365. Has anyone else had this problem? Would using parentheses help?

Comment: What is the line of vba code that raises that error ?

Comment: The date picker is no longer available (and Microsoft failed to provide alternatives). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel/54689596#54689596